# Disabling, overriding or hooking a VS warning to Unity's Vector's ToString()?

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio, .net

I've just spent 2 hours debugging a misbehaviour because **ToString() truncates to 1 digit** by default.

I want to **disable the parameterless version** so I won't use it by accident and I will **always have to define how much truncation** I want.

Or if this isn't possible I want to redefine it, so it will truncate to 3 digits for example.

Or somehow **hook a custom warning to it**, so *Visual Studio* will tell me that I'm using it?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Unity Vectors are structs. Therefore you cannot derive your own vectors and of course not override `ToString()`. You will have to use this other overloaded version:

```
public string ToString(string format)
```

and call it with

```
string s = v.ToString("F3")
```

---

You could also declare an extension method

```
public static class VectorExtensions
{
    public string ToStrStd(this Vector3 v) => v.ToString("F3");
}
```

and use it like this

```
string s = v.ToStrStd()
```

---

I don't think there is an easy way to be warned if you are using the "wrong" version. If you are working with Visual Studio, you could [Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix).